# Iteration over the rows of a Pandas DataFrame as dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I need to iterate over a pandas dataframe in order to pass each row as argument of a function (actually, class constructor) with `**kwargs`. This means that  each row should behave as a dictionary with keys the column names and values the corresponding ones for each row.

This works, but it performs very badly:

```
import pandas as pd


def myfunc(**kwargs):
    try:
        area = kwargs.get('length', 0)* kwargs.get('width', 0)
        return area
    except TypeError:
        return 'Error : length and width should be int or float'


df = pd.DataFrame({'length':[1,2,3], 'width':[10, 20, 30]})

for i in range(len(df)):
    print myfunc(**df.iloc[i])
```

Any suggestions on how to make that more performing ? I have tried iterating with tried `df.iterrows()`,
but I get the following error :

> TypeError: myfunc() argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple

I have also tried `df.itertuples()` and `df.values` , but either I am missing something, or it means that I have to convert each tuple / np.array to a  pd.Series or dict , which will also be slow.
My constraint is that the script has to work with python 2.7 and pandas 0.14.1.

Comment: Try [DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

Comment: the by far slowest part in your code is the printing of the area. If i try it in python 3 with 10.000 rows i need 1.5 seconds with your variant (no printing), 0.9 seconds using itterrows() and over 3 seconds if i print the areas

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried that, but I do not seem to get how to acess column names for each element of the row.. As for the print, I only wrote that for the sake of executability of the code, it is the iteration performance that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a separate function for this will be inefficient, as you are applying row-wise calculations. More efficient would be to calculate a new series, then iterate the series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'length':[1,2,3,'test'], 'width':[10, 20, 30,'hello']})

df2 = df.iloc[:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

error_str = 'Error : length and width should be int or float'
print(*(df2['length'] * df2['width']).fillna(error_str), sep='\n')

10.0
40.0
90.0
Error : length and width should be int or float
```

Answer (score 71):

one clean option is this one:

```py
for row_dict in df.to_dict(orient="records"):
    print(row_dict['column_name'])
```

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: according to latest docs this is now `orient='records'`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Comment: Or if you want the keys as well use "index" instead of "records". You then also have to use `items()` to iterate over the keys / values

Comment: This is also the best way to iterate over rows without having the issues of **1)** coercing data types like `.iterrows()` does, or **2)** remaning columns with invalid Python identifiers like `itertuples()`does.

Answer (score 24):

You can try:

```
for k, row in df.iterrows():
    myfunc(**row)
```

Here `k` is the dataframe index and `row` is a dict, so you can access any column with: `row["my_column_name"]`

Comment: Good Solution for the case but be aware iterrows are performance hitting in a large dataset [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316)

Comment: That's true I just answered in order to make the iterrows works, but @jpp solution is probably better in terms of performances.

Comment: In reality it's a __pd.Series__ not a __dict__. But it works of couse.